# При компиляции кода выходит ошибка 101. Process finished with exit code 101

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.10

Возникает такая ощибка:

```
"C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Определенная работа\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Определенная работа/Work.py"
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/????????? ??????/Work.py"'

Process finished with exit code 101
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте переименовать папку с проектом, чтобы в названии папки были только латинские буквы.

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент это больше похоже на сбой самого `Python`, актуального с версии 3.8 по 3.11. И да, этот сбой критический и получил своё место в [баг-трекере Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90844).

На данный момент одним из немногих простых решений вопроса является удаление `Python` с последующей переустановкой с выбором `"Установить для всех пользователей"/"Install for all users"`. Другие решения, а также технические детали, если интересно, приведены по ссылке выше.

Comment: Не похоже, что тут именно эта проблема, в ошибке тогда было бы "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/?????????" (путь обрезан по первый пробел). Тут какая-то проблема при перекодировке пути, и возможно поможет перемещение проекта в папку без кириллицы в пути.

Comment: @insolor как вариант тоже может быть — только пускай автор переместит в папку вместе с пробелами тоже. Если ошибка останется, то скорее баг из моего ответа, иначе — пусть хотя бы останется для общего развития :)

Comment: Нет, при написании названия проекта было использовано кириллица из - за это там так пишет